# How can I set up IAM authentication for my API Gateway using AWS SAM?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the below SAM template to create a Lambda function & an API Gateway with `AWS_IAM` auth (IAM authentication):

```yaml
MyDemoLambdaApiFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Currently does not support S3 upload event.
    Handler: app.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.11
    CodeUri: .
    MemorySize: 1028
    Events:
      MyDemoAPI:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          RestApiId: !Ref api
          Path: /gtl
          Method: GET

MyDemoLambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt MyDemoLambdaApiFunction.Arn
    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${api}/*/*'

api:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: "myTestApi"
    StageName: api
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
      InvokeRole: NONE
      ResourcePolicy:
        CustomStatements:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
            Resource: ['execute-api:/api/gtl']
            Principal: "*"
```

When I try to invoke the API URL from a browser, I get:

```json
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

When I remove the `DefaultAuthorizer` section, I am able to invoke the gateway URL from the browser.

I want to only allow API invocation from my AWS account.

I also tried this as the `Principal` but no luck:

```yaml
AWS:
  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/myRole'
```

When do I use AWS_IAM for auth when creating AWS::Lambda::Permission?

Answer (score 0):

Your resource policy is incorrect. You're missing the HTTP verb from your `Resource` element, which results in an invalid ARN being generated.

This prevents the IAM policy from taking effect, potentially not granting you access & locking you out (depending on the identity-based policies that are also applied to your user, that could grant you access without the resource policy applied).

The correct [abbreviated format template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html) is:

> execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard*}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard*}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard*}}

However, the above template incorrectly uses:

> execute-api:/{stageName}/{resourcePath}

To fix this, change `execute-api:/api/gtl` to `execute-api:/api/GET/gtl`.

---

Then, to grant access to just [your account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-accountid), change your principal to:

```yaml
Principal:
  AWS:
    - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
```

---

> When do I use AWS_IAM for auth when creating AWS::Lambda::Permission?

Setting API Gateway authentication relates to controlling & managing access to the API.

Using [`AWS::Lambda::Permission`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) relates to granting function access to other AWS services, accounts and/or organisations (by addding IAM statements to the [Lambda function policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html)).

Regardless of how you configure authentication for your API (or lack thereof using `NONE`), you still need to grant the API Gateway access to invoke your function. That doesn't change.

They're 2 completely different things, taking effect at different points of the request lifecycle.

---

All in all, this should work:

```yaml
api:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: "myTestApi"
    StageName: api
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
      InvokeRole: NONE
      ResourcePolicy:
        CustomStatements:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
            Resource: ['execute-api:/api/GET/gtl']
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
```

Comment: Sorry looks like I am still missing something or probably mis-understood the behavior of API gateway invocation. I tried with Resource: ['execute-api:/api/GET/gtl'] and Principal to have !Ref "AWS::AccountId", but I am still getting ""Missing Authentication Token" when I access the API GW URL from the browser. As I mentioned, I just want my lambda GW URL be accessed from a browser and only within my AWS account.

Comment: How do you want to identify 'your browser'? By IP?

Comment: For now yes by IP, but the gateway needs to be accessible for all users within my AWS account-id.

Comment: The above policy makes it accessible for all users, with the right credentials. You need to sign your requests with the credentials for your IAM user; you can’t just navigate to the URL and expect AWS to know who you are without any info.

Comment: Thank you. Agree AWS can't recognize the user without proper credentials. Where should I look at next for signing the requests?

Comment: You have plenty of options! Any AWS SDK, the AWS CLI, Postman has an ‘AWS credentials’ option, Curl has a AWS SIG v4 option etc.

Comment: Our company likes to use cloudformation script for all needs. So just wondering if this part can be achieved via CFN script?

Comment: CloudFormation has nothing to do with authenticating when calling the API Gateway, unless you are connecting to the API via CFN.